# Azure mod-rewrite to SSL doesn't work

Tags: iis, ssl, azure, url-rewriting

I have deployed an ASP.NET web application to Azure running in a web role. It is configured with a DNS name like 'myapp.cloudapp.net' and SSL (the certificate is self-signed, meaning we get a certificate warning but otherwise this is all set up and works fine)

I want to automagically route requests the come on http to https. So, I added an http endpoint and set up a rewrite rule as per the instructions here (second method):

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/redirecting-to-https-in-windows-azure-two-methods

It doesn't work properly.

Testing directly on the Azure machine (via remote desktop):

- Access https://myapp.cloudapp.net - works
- Access http://myapp.cloudapp.net - "Internet explorer cannot display the webpage"

So I go to IIS and 'browse' my site: this takes me there via the IP address:

- Access https://[ipaddress] - works
- Access http://[ipaddress] - works! Sends me to https://[ipaddress]

So what am I missing, that this works via IP address but not by host name?

I would like to hit http://myapp.cloudapp.net and be redirected to https://myapp.cloudapp.net.

For the record, here is the relevant parts of my configuration:

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="MyApp" />
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="MyAppHttp" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="MyApp" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="MYCERT" />
  <InputEndpoint name="MyAppHttp" protocol="http" port="80" />
</Endpoints>
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="MYCERT" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
</Certificates>
```

Can anyone help explain what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's worth firing up a tool like Fiddler to see if there's a response from the server when you browse to http://myapp.cloudapp.net. But Greg's guess is also good... I would make sure the binding names are different. (I'm somewhat surprised that's not an error.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a lot to go on, but one thing that jumps out at me is the 'name' of your bindings.  Make them different.